# DbProviderFactories in net standard 2.1 cannot be referenced to net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#

I do have my project which uses `.NET Framework 4.7.2` and which is using `.Net Standard 2.0`. Inside net standard class library i want to use `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory` method. Nevertheless i read that `DbProviderFactories` is not available in `.Net Standard 2.0` but it has been added to `2.1`. The problem is `.Net Framework 4.7.2` or even `4.8` cannot reference `.Net standard 2.1`. How to solve that?